# Which is the best way to convert a string to float?

Tags: javascript

I need sum up two number:

```
var n1 = "3.1416";
var n2 = "2.05";

// i could do this as follow:

// method 1:
var sum = parseFloat(n1) + parseFloat(n2)
// method 2:
var sum = eval(n1) + eval(n2)
// method 3:
var sum = (n1 * 1) + (n2 * 1)
// method 4:
var sum = Number(n1) + Number(n2)
// method 5:
var sum = +n1 + (+n2)
// method 6:
var sum = (n1-0) + (n2-0)
// method 7:
var sum = (n1/1) + (n2/1)
```

any others?

Which one of this is a less error prone? Why?

Comment: What does "best" mean to you? And what is your intent with this question?

Comment: I mean the most correct way in javascript and less error prone

Comment: `Number` makes the most sense, because it is explicit and returns `NaN` for non-numeric input.

Comment: @FelixKling method 3 appears to be equivalent to method 4, both returns NaN

Comment: Yes, but it's less explicit (same for the unary plus operator (i.e. +n1), which I actually preferred for a long while).

Comment: thats neat: +n1 +(+n2)

Comment: `eval` is absolutely **evil** in this case. Please, don't even suggest that.

Comment: @tadman It's really not. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @tadman check this: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/

Comment: @Borachio We're adding numbers here. There is zero excuse to use `eval`. It's like stirring soup with a loaded gun. Sure, you can, you *probably* won't shoot yourself, but why take the risk?

Comment: @tadman You're absolutely right, but *evil* isn't the right word for that reasoning. It's definitely silly and completely unnecessary to use, but I don't understand how you can compare it to a loaded gun - you seem to be following the fad of hating `eval` without reason. It would be much more helpful if you gave true reasoning for why not to use `eval`, because Borachio's link is pretty spot on

Comment: @Ian Here's the thing: I'd rather people irrationally feared `eval` than people irrationally used it. It's intended to be a tool of last resort, the thing use use when all other options are exhausted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what you want the result to be if the input is not correct.

One thing is sure, you don't want to use `eval`. Besides being associated with cross site scripting attacks because it runs the string as code rather than just parsing it, it will also crash the script if the input is not completely valid.

Using `* 1` hides the real intention of the code. Multiplying something with one is a useless operation as it doesn't change the value at all, so the goal to have the value converted is hidden in the implicit operation that precedes the multiplication.

What those two do, are covered by the other methods (except crashing), so you never need to use them anyway.

The `parseFloat` and `Number` functions clearly convey what you are trying to do, but they differ in how they handle input that may or may not be interpreted as a number. Here are some examples:

```
input     parseFloat    Number

"3.14"       3.14        3.14
"3.14x"      3.14         NaN
"x3.14"       NaN         NaN
""            NaN           0
```

Answer (score 1):

parseFloat is the best. In case your string begins with "non numbers" values, parseFloat will return NaN which stands for Not a Number so be careful.

```
parseFloat('1.2foobar'); // this will be (float) 1.2
```

And this :

```
parseFloat('foobar1.2'); // this will be NaN
```

You can see the documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) and try it yourself

Comment: Not true, `parseFloat('1.2foo')` returns `1.2`.

Comment: With Number() its possible to address NaN and call the appropriate function to handle the error.

Comment: i mean, its possible to use isNaN when a bad string like "3.14a" should be avoid

Comment: it depends on what you want to do really

Answer (score 0):

Go with "**parseFloat**", since it will most clearly convey your [**intention**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intentional_programming).

Comment: Do you say intention as the same concept as convention?

Comment: No, I mean that you should try to display the intention with the piece of code for whomever is reading it (And possibly maintaining it) after you.